# Traditional 2D CNN Formula

Tags: machine-learning

In [[4D U-Nets for Multi-Temporal Remote Sensing Data Classification]](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/14/3/634) they give the following formula for the traditional 2D CNN. But I’m confused about the w_i,j in this formula:

[image]

From my knowledge I would say that if you have a NxNxd input, your kernel will have shape HxWxd in this case. So the ‘depth’ of the kernel matches the ‘depth’ of the input. In this formula it seems that they are re-using the same HxW kernel against every ‘depth’ level d.

I would therefore say that it should be w_i,j,c instead of w_i,j.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I believe you're right. It appears they broadcast filter coefficients across the channel dimension.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are correct. They make the same mistake on the formula for a 3D-CNN. These appear to be misquoted/mis-copied from their cited reference, Ji et al.'s [3D Convolutional Neural Networks for Crop Classification with Multi-Temporal Remote Sensing Images](https://www.mdpi.com/2072-4292/10/1/75), who show the 2D convolutional operation as:

$$y_{cd}=\sigma\left(\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=0}^M w_{ij,n}x_{(c+i)(d+j),n}+b\right)$$

and the 3D convolutional operation as:

$$y_{cde}=\sigma\left(\sum_{n=0}\sum_{k=0}^N\sum_{i=0}^M\sum_{j=0}^M w_{kij,n}x_{(c+i)(d+j)(e+k),n}+b\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it makes sense